# How to set a marker on a specific bar in python graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code to generate a stacked bar graph.

```
width=.35
m1_t = pd.DataFrame({
'System':[13.77,40.72,114.59,141.71,174.59, 217.95, 237.26, 261.8,  297.46, 332.25, 366.08, 351.9,404.33,436.06,465.13, 494.56, 497.43, 526.82, 545.34, 563.61, 581.92, 594.94, 610.23, 665.7,  688.82],
'Cloud':[699.52,673.49, 601.76, 577.89,546.8,502.07,484.37,460.50,424.14,387.32,351.01,316.27,312.93,279.82,247.59,214.86,  183.4,182.47,163.05,143.42,123.92,111.27,96.27,39.95,16.98],
'Communication':[942.4,18072,18072,5019.2,  9000,9000,2510.4,5019.2,5019.2,5019.2,5019.2,1256,2510.4,2510.4,2510.4,2510.4,628.8,628.8,628.8,628.8,628.8,144,144,272,272],
'Output_data': [0.589,12.545,12.545,3.137,6.273,6.273,1.569,3.137,3.137,3.137,3.137,0.785,  1.569,1.569,1.569,1.569,0.393,0.393,0.393,0.393,0.393,0.09,0.09,0.17,0.17]})

colors = ['#5DADE2', 'orange', '#D5DBDB', '#273746', '#FFDEAD']
m1_t[['System','Cloud','Communication']].plot(kind='bar', width = width,stacked=True,color=colors,figsize=(6.5, 3))
plt.ylabel("Latency (ms)")
# plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim(0, 20000)
m1_t['Output_data'].plot(secondary_y=True, color='darkslategrey', marker='o', MarkerSize=2)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.xlim([-width, len(m1_t['Communication']) - width])
plt.xticks(rotation=45, size=2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14','15', '16', '17', '18', '19','20','21','22','23','24','25'))
plt.ylim(0, 14)
plt.ylabel("Output-data (MB)")
plt.show()
```

I need to define a round marker on a specific bar and its legend too (in this case bar 17) like the one in the following link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ER8PFzQLzLSsH25A_jvl9xLlQJ-R320T/view?usp=sharing. I tried different solutions however I am unable to accomplish this. Thank you for help

Comment: Just want to clarify, you want to have a dot (a single marker) on particularly just bar number 17, as well as a legend for it?
If yes, have you considered about making a single dot with ``ax.scatter(x, y, label=label)`` and ``ax.legend()`` after that?

Comment: Hi @Karina, thanks yes just a single marker on bar number 17 as well as legend for it. I will try for what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this one:

```
ax.scatter(16, m1_t['Output_data'][16], label='test label', marker='*', c='r')
ax.legend(loc='center right')
```

--edit--

change:

```
m1_t['Output_data'].plot(secondary_y=True, color='darkslategrey', marker='o', MarkerSize=2)
ax.scatter(16, m1_t['Output_data'][16], label='test label', marker='*', c='r')
```

to:

```
m1_t['Output_data'].plot(secondary_y=True, color='darkslategrey', marker='o', MarkerSize=2, zorder=0)
ax.scatter(16, m1_t['Output_data'][16], label='test label', marker='*', c='r', zorder=1)
```

the parameter you are looking for is `zorder`

Comment: Thanks @Karina it works fine but I noticed the  (marker) star is hidden I want the star to be up of the bar.

Comment: See my updated answer. Tried to give the update as a comment but it looks too complicated.